# redirect looping on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, loops, redirect, html-helper, infinity

After i had changed my codeigniter files  and the screen has diplay error like this

> http://webdomain.com/index.php/login/login has resulted
>   in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing
>   third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a
>   server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer. Learn
>   more about this problem. Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

It might cause by the infinity looping redirect and i tried fix a few hour i don't where the problem there is  my code but i cant figure it out whats the error in my code and i used google chrome for the browser

my route default controller is index.php

here is the login.php (controller) code

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('error');

class Login extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('security');        
}

public function index(){
    redirect('login/login');
}

public function login(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==TRUE){
            redirect ('login/login');
        }else{
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            //for view filters
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|min_length[5]|max_length[125]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]');
            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                $this->load->view('login/login_admin');
            }else{
                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $password = $this->input->post('password');

                //$this->load->model('login_model');
                $query=$this->Login_model->data_pengguna($username,$password,1);
                    if($query->num_rows()==1){
                        //jika benar
                        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                            $this->load->library('encrypt');
                            //generate hash password
                            $hash=$this->encrypt->sha1($password);
                            //mengcompare result hash in database\
                            if($hash!=$row->hash){
                                //tidak sama
                                $data['login_fail']=true;
                                $this->load->view('login/login_admin',$data);

                            }else{
                                $data=array(
                                    'id'=>$row->user_id,
                                    'username'=>$row->username,
                                    'logged_in'=>TRUE
                                );
                                //menyimpan session
                                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                                redirect ('login/home');
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }


public function logout(){

    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login/login_admin');
}
}

?>
```

and here is the login_model.php (model) code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Login_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function get_pengguna($username, $password, $status){
        $this->db->select('username','password','status');
        $this->db->from('userlogin');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $this->db->where('status',$status);
        $query= $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    public function data_pengguna($username){
        $this->db->select('username');
        $this->db->from('userlogin');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $query= $this->db->get('userlogin');
        return $query->row();
    }
}
?>
```

and here is the view login_admin.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Admin Login</title>

    <style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:100,200,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700,400,300);

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;

    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.body{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    right: -40px;
    bottom: -40px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url(http://ginva.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/city-skyline-wallpapers-008.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: 0;
}

.grad{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    right: -40px;
    bottom: -40px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 35px);
    left: calc(50% - 255px);
    z-index: 2;
}

.header div{
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.header div span{
    color: #5379fa !important;
}

.login{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 75px);
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.login input[type=text]{
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 4px;
}

.login input[type=password]{
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.login input[type=button]{
    width: 260px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #a18d6c;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.login input[type=button]:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.login input[type=button]:active{
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.login input[type=text]:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.login input[type=password]:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.login input[type=button]:focus{
    outline: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder{
   color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

::-moz-input-placeholder{
   color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
</style>

    <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<?php echo form_open('login/login');?>
<?php if (validation_errors()):?>
<h3>There Something Error</h3>
<p><?php echo validation_errors();?></p>
<?php endif;?>
  <div class="body"></div>
        <div class="grad"></div>
        <div class="header">
            <div>Login<span>Admin</span></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="login">

                <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username');?>" class="inputan" <?php echo form_error('username');?>> <br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password')?>" class="inputan" <?php echo form_error('username');?> ><br>
                <input type="button" value="Login">
        </div>

  <script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
<?php form_close();?>
</body>

</html>
```

and then this .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|styles|scripts|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Stuck for few hours in this problem.. i am also wondering why changed hosting cause such problem.

thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in one of my project.

I see the problem is in index function and login check condition in login function.

You can refer the below -

```
public function index($msg = NULL){
    $this->is_logged_in(); //here i've added the condition to check whether user is logged in
    ['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}

public function login(){ 
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->login_model->validate(); //validating the user into model

    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result){ 
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index($msg);
    }else{            
            $this->redirect_other();
    }        
} //end function login()
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the first is logged in check from your login function, as you said default function is index in which you are calling login/ login. Yoy do not need to repear it again.